# convertTo not working in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use convertTo() in opencv C++. But an error pops saying

> left of:convertTo must have class/struct/union

the program is below:

```
for (i = 0; i < height; i += 8)
{
    for (j = 0; j < width; j += 8)
    {
        Mat block = dctImage(Rect(j, i, 8, 8));
        vector<Mat> planes;
        split(block, planes);
        vector<Mat> outplanes(planes.size());
        for (k = 0; k < planes.size(); k++) {
            planes[k].convertTo(planes[k], CV_32FC1);
            dct(planes[k], outplanes[k]);
            outplanes[k].convertTo(outplanes[k], CV_8UC1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works for me... Please post an [mcve]

Comment: Did you make sure to use the correct OpenCV-dlls for your Visual Studio version (if you're using vs)? Sometimes this causes weird program behaviors. I once forgot that the folder VC12 is not for VS2012 and got problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `.convertTo()` can handle the case of identical source and destination. You may want to try using a pair of temporary variables to get around your error message. Here is the relevant part from your example:

```
    // ...
    for (k = 0; k < planes.size(); k++) {
        Mat planes_k, outplanes_k;                     // <-- Added temporaries.
        planes[k].convertTo(planes_k, CV_32FC1);
        dct(planes_k, outplanes_k);
        outplanes_k.convertTo(outplanes[k], CV_8UC1);
    }
    // ...
```

**UPDATE**

According to the [source code of `.convertTo()`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/convert.cpp#L4807) my suggestion isn't really required (thanks pointing this out, @boaz001).

Comment: This is not necessary. If the type of the destination does not match with the source it is reallocated. This can be validated by printing the ```planes[k].type()``` before/after the ```convertTo```.

Comment: @boaz001 Hmm, it seems that you're right. According to the [source code of `.convertTo()`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/convert.cpp#L4807) my suggestion isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The Left:of statement suggests that its null or undefined 
i.e. 
outplanes[k] does not contain what you think it should.

I did a quick search and it looks like this could be a compiler issue whereby it has difficulty understanding/interpreting the line ...

```
vector<Mat> outplanes(planes.size());
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

What is outplanes? Is it being instantiated correctly?

The 'Most_vexing_parse' article suggests helping the compiler with extra parenthesis

```
vector<Mat> outplanes((planes.size()));
```

Kinda depends on your code and what the outplanes method/class is actually doing, but i imagine it's not returning what you think it should be.